# Displaying black background pixels in RGB raster as transparent (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity

I have the following RGB raster and would like to remove the black background (where R=0, G=0, B=0). I'm using QGIS.

The problem is that the raster itself also contains black pixels. Using the option of QGIS to make all RGB(0,0,0) pixels transparent is therefore not an option, since it will make some of the lines transparent as well. Are there any other options?

[image]

Comment: Did you check what is the value of NODATA ?

Comment: The raster seems to be reprojected. Can you get hold of the unprojected source, which lets you allow to set a different NODATA value during reprojection?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [nearblack](http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) gdal utility for make raster with transparent background.

Comment: Those pixels are already totally black and transparent, nearblack is made for different purpose. Lossy compression methods like jpeg or ecw are sometimes changing pixel values a bit and (0 0 0) may become for example (0 1 0). Nearblack is introducing some tolerance which makes that (0 1 0) as nodata again. Useful tool but not relevant for handling this issue.

Comment: RGB raster can not be displayed without loss (if you set NODATA to 0 0 0). Useful method - convert to RGBA and change 'frame' pixels to transparent value. Nearblack can be used for this case.

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong and nearblack may be the right tool. Have a try with -setalpha and -setmask (use -o for creating new image for output). Algorithm may be clever enough for skipping the nodata pixels within the data area.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-fix, though inelegant, is to create a vector layer with a polygon that matches the shape of the raster area you want. Colour the polygon black and place the new vector layer below the raster layer. Those irritating transparent pixels will be rendered over a black 'background' and will appear to be black again.